# SDL_Surface not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sdl, surface

I seem to be having an issue with the use of SDL_Surface(s).

This is my header file (CApp.h):

```
#ifndef _CAPP_H_
    #define _CAPP_H_

#include <SDL.h>

class CApp {
    private:
        bool            Running;

        SDL_Surface*    Surf_Display;

    public:
        CApp();

        int OnExecute();

    public:
        bool OnInit();

        void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);

        void OnLoop();

        void OnRender();

        void OnCleanup();
};

#endif
```

and this is where the problem lies:

```
#include "CApp.h"

CApp::CApp() {
    Surf_Display = NULL;
    Running = true;
}

int CApp::OnExecute() {
    if(OnInit() == false) {
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Event Event;

    while(Running) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)) {
            OnEvent(&Event);
        }

        OnLoop();
        OnRender();
    }

    OnCleanup();

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
//Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
    CApp theApp;

    return theApp.OnExecute();
}
```

The error say `'Surf_Display' was not declared in this scope.`

Comment: So which is it, `SDL_Surface`, or `Surf_Display` not declared in the scope?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with this code. Try pasting the exact error.

Comment: I managed to build this code without any problems - I just had to remove the functions that you haven't written yet.

Comment: Did you include the lib in your compile line?